# NServiceBus 4 code based configuration in Azure not working

Tags: azure, nservicebus

I am working with the RC2 of Nservicebus 4 and the PubSub sample downloaded from the below location:
http://particular.net/articles/windows-azure-transport

I am trying to do a code based configuration (instead of the azure csfg file as is shown in the sample). This works on earlier versions of NServiceBus so i am not sure what i am missing here. The custom configuration is not being picked up. Is this a bug?

Here are the changes i made that should duplicate the problem.

1. Removed the nservicebus configuration from the webrole settings
2. Replaced those same configuration settings in a custom IConfigurationSource and removed the AzureConfigurationSource from the bus bootstrap code.

**Here is the changed bootstrap code in the Global.asax.cs file:**

```
  var bus = Configure.With()
                .DefaultBuilder()
                .CustomConfigurationSource(new CustomConfig())
                .MessageForwardingInCaseOfFault()
                .AzureMessageQueue()
                    .QueuePerInstance()
                .UnicastBus()
                .CreateBus()
            .Start();
```

**Here is the CustomConfig class:**

```
internal class CustomConfig : IConfigurationSource
{
    public T GetConfiguration<T>() where T : class, new()
    {
        // the part you are overriding
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(AzureQueueConfig))
            return new AzureQueueConfig { ConnectionString = "storage key here", QueueName = "orderwebsiteinputqueue" } as T;

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig))
            return new MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig { ErrorQueue = "errorqueue"} as T;

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(TransportConfig))
            return new TransportConfig() { MaxRetries = 5, MaximumConcurrencyLevel = 1} as T;

        // leaving the rest of the configuration as is:
        return ConfigurationManager.GetSection(typeof(T).Name) as T;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to customize the configuration is to implement IProvideConfiguration instead of replacing the configuration source, can you try that?

Kind regards,
Yves

Comment: Thanks! That does work. However, the problem is that this was working previously so i will need to change my existing endpoints to use this method instead of the IConfigurationSource. I would recommend changing the documentation to indicate that this is not the preferred method or marking this as obsolete so users do not hit the same wall that I did. Most users will not catch (at least for the queue config creds) this until they try to go beyond the local emulator because, as you know, the default connection is dev storage and using a custom config source appears to work locally but doesn't.

Comment: i just discovered that the ICustomconfigurationSource works for a console project that is using an azure transport. So the problem seems to only be for azure hosted projects. To test this i bootstrapped a console project as a client and registered an AzureQueueConfig config source and it worked.

Comment: Found the culprit, looks like line 29 in https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/blob/develop/src/azure/NServiceBus.Azure/Transports/StorageQueues/Config/AzureStorageQueueTransport.cs needs an additional check to see if a custom source has been configured already.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the quick work. The other thing i noticed which may not be related but is related to configuration is that there has to be at least the AzureProfileConfig.Profiles in the azure configuration or else it will complain.

Comment: just an fyi, i will be posting another similar issue related to DataBus configuration as well.